# What prevent a web service from doing image recognition on an image of Illinois resident?

Tags: amazon-clouddrive

On the bottom of this Amazon Cloud Drive TOS : https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201376540

> 6.6 Notice to Illinois Residents. The image recognition features of the Services are not initially enabled for residents of the State of
>   Illinois. If you are an Illinois resident and wish to use the image
>   recognition features of the Services for the photos stored in your
>   account, you are required to read and agree to the important legal
>   information regarding your use of such features here.

I wonder what is the problem of this particular state? Note that "here" leads to a broken link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is an issue around whether facial recognition is legal or not. See the article below:

http://www.forbes.com/sites/legalnewsline/2016/07/05/il-facial-recognition-law-leads-to-wave-of-class-actions-against-facebook-others/#52ac17294e56